# AppHarbor hardware environment

Tags: .net, performance, appharbor

Is it possible to find out how much memory an appharbor instance has available to it?

The reason I ask is that I have a site which does heavy data transformation to create reports on the fly. I am finding that the same reports in my AppHarbor instance perform 3 to 4 times worse compared to my development environment. This is running the same computations over the same data set. Specifically, reports which take 4 seconds to run in development take about 15 seconds on AppHarbor.

To make it worse I am developing in a Parallel's VM restricted to 2GB memory on a Macbook Air - not exactly a workhorse development environment.

My AppHarbor instance has the ambiguously named "2 workers per unit" at the moment.

So my question is .. what are the actual specs I am running on, and would there be any recommendations for improving it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the current resource allocations and limits for a worker unit in [the program policy](https://appharbor.com/page/programpolicy). These are subject to change, but currently a worker unit include 512MB RAM. This means you can get up to 2GB RAM per worker by [scaling vertically](http://blog.appharbor.com/2013/03/13/introducing-vertical-scaling-make-your-workers-better-faster-and-stronger).

It's not clear from your question whether you're using web workers to generate these reports, but I'd also recommend using [AppHarbor's background workers](http://support.appharbor.com/kb/getting-started/background-workers) to execute these workloads.

Comment: Interesting. I will try scaling vertically. I am using web workers to generate the reports as that's the point of the site, so moving to background workers is not really an option.

A further question though - I think I will increase to 4 worker units per worker for the vertical scaling. However this seems to make my background worker quadruple in cost as well. Is it possible to vertically scale web and background workers seperateley?

Comment: To answer my own question, perhaps I could just create a second application, point it at the main application's DB and run my data crunching tasks on it?

Comment: Separating the web and background workers into two apps have a few drawbacks, and may in some cases be in violation with the terms. However for the time being I think this sounds like the most sensible approach and a valid use case. Feel free to reach out directly on support@appharbor.com if you'd like us to take a closer look. We'll make sure to update this question as soon as you can vertically scale the web/background worker types separately as well.

Comment: Also, I can recommend checking out [Compilify](http://compilify.com/) for an example of how to use web and background workers to provide a smooth, responsive user experience, where the majority of the workload is seamlessly handled by background workers using a simple queueing mechanism. The source code is available on GitHub and [the worker's Program file](https://github.com/Compilify/Compilify/blob/master/Worker/Program.cs) is particularly interesting to see how the integration with the Cloud AMQP add-on can be handled.